# Keytab setup in AWS Glue to connect SQL server using SPARK(using Active Directory)

Tags: apache-spark, active-directory, aws-glue

I am trying to use active directory credentials to extract from MS SQL Server from AWS Glue(using spark). but getting token errors. Set up is working fine with local user credentials.

I have read about setting up keytab and use service principal along with it but could not achieve it with AWS Glue

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/spark-mssql-connector?view=sql-server-ver15

Any Thoughts? please share

Comment: hey @msmb, did you get this work? If so, kindly share